# "-/+ buffers/cache memory" is zero

Tags: apache2, php, ram, memory-usage, vps

i have an OpenVZ VPS with ubuntu server 14.04.2 and i can access to a SolusVM control panel. Recently, "memory usage" is always 0 KB, and only "vswap usage" shows real swap usage.

if i run `free -k` i get

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        262144     121728     140416      69160          0     121728
-/+ buffers/cache:          0     262144
Swap:       131072          0     131072
```

and if i run `cat /proc/meminfo` i get:

```
MemTotal:         262144 kB
MemFree:          140416 kB
Cached:           121728 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:            53208 kB
Inactive:          62944 kB
Active(anon):      29864 kB
Inactive(anon):    29872 kB
Active(file):      23344 kB
Inactive(file):    33072 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        131072 kB
SwapFree:         131072 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         59736 kB
Shmem:             69160 kB
Slab:               5568 kB
SReclaimable:       2064 kB
SUnreclaim:         3504 kB
```

Why is the "-/+ buffers/cache" memory usage always zero?

Comment: Looks like your host's kernel has a bug: it is reporting that all 121 mb of used memory is in the cache, even though you can see from adding the active and inactive file sets up that there really is only 56mb in the cache.

Comment: i just find out that if i disable php5 mod from apache2 service "buffers/cache" memory usage shows correct usage...
Any idea how to fix it?